# HTML and Flask POST Image Upload Stopped Working

Tags: python, html, opencv, flask, post

My flask/html POST image upload system has worked in the past but now I am seeing that the image is not being uploaded to the folder it is supposed to be uploaded to. The error message I receive when I run the server is targeted at the compression of the image and says 'Nonetype has no attribute shape' which caused by what I assume to be the image failing to upload. As I said in the title, this code has worked in the past and sometimes when the code didn't refreshing the server would fix the errors. The HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css') }}">
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method=POST id="submitbox" enctype=multipart/form-data action="{{ url_for('upload') }}">
    <input type=file name=photo>
    <input type="submit" id="submittext">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The python code:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
            global file_name
            file_name = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
            print(file_name)
            global file_path
            file_path = os.path.join(r'FILEPATH', file_name)
            print(file_path)
            img = cv2.imread(file_path)
            height, width, _ = img.shape
            roi = img[0: height, 0: width]
            _, compressedimage = cv2.imencode(".jpg", roi, [1, 90]
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

line 304, in upload
height, width, _ = img.shape
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: always put ful error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screnshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you can use `io.bytes` to create file in memory - and then you don't have save it on disk to read it with `cv2` or with `pillow`

Comment: do you use folder with name `r'FILEPATH'` or it should be variable `FILEPATH` ?

Comment: first check if  `photos.save()` saved file in place which you expect. Maybe it save in different folder then you expect or it had problem to save it (ie. full disk)

Comment: I put in an actual file path there and not a variable such as r'C:\users\user\app\images\' where the FILEPATH variable is

Comment: check if `file_path` is correct - check if you can open this full path in any viewer.

Comment: Usually storing in a different folder works for a while and then stops working. Not a full disk as I have a lot of free space. I may try the io.bytes but I don't know how to implement that into the beginning part of the code.

Comment: The directory is a real directory I can navigate to. The filename added to the end is not a file there although.